# Windows authentication in IIS Express over VPN

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I am working on a C# .Net MVC application that uses Windows authentication.  When I am in the office, on my work computer, all is well.  However, the same code base on my personal laptop will not authenticate.  I'm not sure what username:password combination it is looking for.  I have tried both my local credentials and my work credentials.  I am connected via VPN to the office and can browse network resources, connect to SQL servers, etc.  I suppose to complicate matters, I log into my personal laptop using a Microsoft account (which I am considering dumping).

Is there any other info that you need?  What else can I try.  I can't figure out where the entry point into my code is happening to attempt a debug.

Comment: We have the same setup, however, our authentication happens via cookies not by what account is logged in(not sure this even possible with it being a web app and all). The issue could be down to DNS issues. If not configured correctly, then whilst on the VPN, the mis-configured DNS records might be blocking you from seeing your app.

Comment: It could also be remembering a previous cookie. have you tried clearing your cache? Is authentication simply failing or do you get redirected to an error page? Are there any exceptions in the 'output' window if debugging using VS? Are you using Azure AD to authenticate?